# Split an array of hashes in two based on the value of a key

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can split this array of hashes in two based on the value of the `ate` key?

```
array = [
  { name: "Gad", ate: true },
  { name: "Lad", ate: false },
  { name: "Bad", ate: true },
  { name: "Sad", ate: false }
]
```

Example output

```
array_1 = [
  { name: "Gad", ate: true },
  { name: "Bad", ate: true }
]
array_2 = [
  { name: "Lad", ate: false },
  { name: "Sad", ate: false }
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method:

```
array.partition { |x| x[:ate] }
# => [[{:name=>"Gad", :ate=>true}, {:name=>"Bad", :ate=>true}], 
#     [{:name=>"Lad", :ate=>false}, {:name=>"Sad", :ate=>false}]]
```

Or:

```
array_1, array_2 = array.partition { |x| x[:ate] }

array_1
# => [{:name=>"Gad", :ate=>true}, {:name=>"Bad", :ate=>true}]

array_2
# => [{:name=>"Lad", :ate=>false}, {:name=>"Sad", :ate=>false}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array_one, array_two = *array.group_by { |x| x[:ate] }.map(&:last)

=> array_one
=> # [{:name=>"Gad", :ate=>true}, {:name=>"Bad", :ate=>true}]
=> array_two
=> # [{:name=>"Lad", :ate=>false}, {:name=>"Sad", :ate=>false}]
```

thx [@CarySwoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland)

Answer (score 2):

I can't compete with `partition`, but here's another way:

```
trues  = array.select { |h| h[:ate] }
falses = array - trues
```